# How to add elements stored in a file to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a file which contains data elements as follows:

```
1749 12426 19597 38042 43350 52873 67704 75875 81829 96307

11615 16454 20015 27021 52762 66631 70625 83951 96527 96893

3370 5530 28692 39087 50591 59442 61906 69337 70643 91162

1947 4604 9657 16455 21149 22739 32809 66089 73871 97304

3429 5325 7888 24101 28851 31637 32424 57991 62470 65017
```

I am facing problem to add each element of the file on different index of array. While searching from internet i was only able to store all of the first row on index array[0].
(All line was stored on the index[0])

I want to store all the column elements array

```
array[0] = 1749 
array[1] = 11615 
array[2] = 3370
array[3] = 1947
array[4] = 3429
```

In second pass:

```
array[0] = 12426
array[1] = 16454
array[2] = 5530 
array[3] = 4604 
array[4] = 5325
```

And so on up to 10th pass.....
PLEASE make necessary changes in the code given below:

```
File            file = new File("SortedLines.txt");
FileInputStream fis  = null;

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    int content;

    while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
        // convert to char and display it
        System.out.print((char)content);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So you'll overwrite the elements in each pass, right?

Comment: `PLEASE make necessary changes in the code given below` your code beside reading each characters in your file has nothing to do with problem you are describing. Maybe try something yourself first (Scanner class can be helpful here) and come back when you will get different results than expected, or some errors. Try to maybe read each line, split it on space and read n-th element you ware interested in.

Comment: Simply store all the lines in String `ArrayList` and the separate each nos using `String.split()` method you'll get each no as separate no then add them

Comment: yes i want to over write elements in each pass

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file lne by line, and for each line, split by spaces add the number to the array:

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>(0);

//Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

    // split by space
    String[] numbers= strLine.split(" ");

    for(String num numbers){
        myArray.add(strLine);  
    }

  }
```

Comment: i am not able to implement it. can u please write the exact code. i m getting a lot of errors if i m pasting your code